# Which is the better way to declare string in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, variables, char

I'm new to C language and I'm very curious about the best way to declare string in c.

Example:

```
char *name;
//or char name[];

scanf("%s", &name);
printf("Hello %s !", name);
```

Which of these two will be better in this case?

```
char *name;
char name[];
```

Comment: It really depends on your use-case, what you're doing with the string.

Comment: Also note that the last, using `[]`, is invalid as you don't provide a size. Arrays must have a size, except in one special situation ([flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)).

Comment: Oh, and remember that while literal strings are not constant, they can't be modified (and are effectively read-only), which is why it's recommended to use `const char *` if you want a pointer to a literal string.

Comment: If you have `char *name;` then `scanf("%s", &name)` is wrong for *two* reasons: 1) The `%s` specifier expects an argument of type `char *`, while `&name` is of type `char **`; 2) Once 1 is fixed, then the pointer `name` is uninitialized and will either be a null pointer (if defined as global variable), or have an indeterminate (and random/garbage) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string with constant length. You can declare an array of *char* like this.

```c
char name[64];


scanf("%s", name); // no more than 63 characters, remember the '\0'
printf("Hello %s\n", name);
```

If the string length is dynamic, please use the function *malloc* to allocate a specific length of memory. What's more you should remember to *free* the memory allocated before.

Comment: You could force `scanf` to not overflow the buffer, by using the format `%63s`.

Answer (score 0):

`char *name;` is a pointer which points the address of the of the first index of your string. This is mostly use if your manipulating the variable by reference eg(passing parameter by reference)

`char name[]` is not applicable in C since you must initialise your array size e.g. `char name[20];`

Either way, the latter with the correct syntax is better.